# security.yml in Symfony2 doesn't authenticate

Tags: symfony

My Symfony App is not working right in a secured directory. I enter my user and pass and the windows is opening again and again. As the user or pass are wrong... This is the code I'm using.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Area"

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    louis: { password: louispass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/backend$, roles: ROLE_USER }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Comment: I think the firewall is missing: see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

Comment: What web server do you use? I think HTTP basic auth is not working in some case. I had the same problem with IIS and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. { path: ^/backend$, roles: ROLE_USER } - only .../backend

**or** { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_USER } - other .../backend...

2. path: ^/backend, roles: **ROLE_ADMIN**

try:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Area"

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    louis: { password: louispass, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }


    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

in case of problems: [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/book/security.html)

All users - { path: ^/login-form, roles: **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY**  }

Comment: Not working, I'm using apache2.4, is like I enter a wrong username or password...